# vue.js 2. Get запрос и експорт в data?

Tags: javascript, get, vue.js, async-await, асинхронность

Здравствуйте!

Нужно отправить get запрос, получить ответ, и работать с ответом. Примерно такой код должен быть, запрос реализован с помощью axios. Но вот только такой код не работает. Ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

Как правильно отправлять запрос и занести его в `data`? Спасибо)

**Код:**

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import async from 'async'


export default {
    name: 'app',
    data: async () => {
        let items = await Axios.get('/getItems');
        return {
            items: items
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` это ошибка транспайлера, он конвертирует `async` в генераторы, попробуйте перенастроить свой транспайлер, посмотрите вот этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, тогда так.

```
  data () {
    return {
      items: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getItems () {
      let { items } = await Axios.get('/getItems');
      this.items = items; 
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getItems();
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, немного модифицировал, и помогло)